# What is a regular expression for a MAC Address?

Tags: regex

In this format:

```
3D:F2:C9:A6:B3:4F
```

or:

```
3D-F2-C9-A6-B3-4F
```

Answer (score 336, accepted):

> The standard (IEEE 802) format for
>   printing MAC-48 addresses in
>   human-friendly form is six groups of
>   two hexadecimal digits, separated by
>   hyphens `-` or colons `:`.

So:

```
^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$
```

Comment: Ok this is what I was looking for, but I had: ^([0-9A-F]{2}:|-){5}([0-9A-F]{2})$

Comment: I was thinking the : | - would match either and : or a -.

Comment: Note that if they are being stored with lower case hexadecimal letters it will not match change the group to [0-9A-Fa-f] to catch both cases

Comment: you probably also want to ignore casing

Comment: Is there a way to only validate it if and only if it has hyphens or colons, for example, it can't have a mixture because of the above regular expression: 3D:F2:C9:A6:B3-4F is valid when it should not be.

Comment: @Xiasoft you must then do two checks like JYelton's example but you could still use the shortened form.

Comment: @Xaisoft: Still according to IEEE 802, 3D:F2:C9:A6:B3-4F is a valid MAC address representation.

Comment: @netcoder, where did u find this info?  I found that a valid MAC is either  sepearted by :, -, or 4 groups separted by .

Comment: @Xaisoft: I recall it's in the OUI spec. I found that out when I was asking myself the same question a while ago. In any case, if you really want to enforce one OR the other, you can do two checks like Scott said.

Comment: ^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$

Comment: As an aside, the quote above concerning "standard format" comes from Wikipedia, not the 802.3 standards body.  IEEE 802-2014 actually specifies _hyphens_ for ordinary MAC addresses (§ 8.1 ¶ 3) and _colons_ for the obsolescent bit-reversed notation (¶ 4).  Importantly, in practice, _no one observes this_.  We simply use one or the other, but never mix them in a single written MAC.

Comment: I don't think that this RegEx is correct as it also classifies 
'3D-F2-C9:A6-B3:4F' 
as a valid MAC Address, even though it is not correct.
The correct one would be:
((([a-zA-z0-9]{2}[-:]){5}([a-zA-z0-9]{2}))|(([a-zA-z0-9]{2}:){5}([a-zA-z0-9]{2})))
So that every time you can choose ':' or '-' for the whole MAC address.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for why you wrap the last two statements into parentheses?

Comment: Note that on macOS, MAC addresses are sometimes printed as "1:0:5e:0:0:0" (e.g. the output of "arp -a"). So even if IEEE 802 says 2 hex digits, 1-2 hex digits may be preferred: ^([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2})$

Answer (score 34):

A little hard on the eyes, but this:

```
/^(?:[[:xdigit:]]{2}([-:]))(?:[[:xdigit:]]{2}\1){4}[[:xdigit:]]{2}$/
```

will enforce either all colons or all dashes for your MAC notation.

(A simpler regex approach might permit `A1:B2-C3:D4-E5:F6`, for example, which the above rejects.)

Comment: This works, but can you explain what :xdigit is? and I noticed you put the group ([-:]) after the length, what makes that take either all colons or hyphens?

Comment: @Xaisoft, `:xdigit:` is short for hex digit, more-or-less another way of saying `[a-fA-F0-9]`.  The `\1` refers to the capture group for the first dash or colon `([-:])`, and only matches what matched that first time.

Comment: +1 for using both capturing and non-capturing groups appropriately, and also for using ```:xdigit:``` (even though that "shorthand" is only just shorter than ```[a-fA-F0-9]``` and equivalent  ```/[a-f0-9]/i``` is shorter!)

Comment: @pilcrow could you please explain why this mac: `C8:FD:19:55:E6:3A` fails? It's an actual mac address. I modified your regex to accept `:` only `/^(?:[[:xdigit:]]{2}([:]))(?:[[:xdigit:]]{2}\1){4}[[:xdigit:]]{2}$/` Thanks!

Comment: @Sam, perhaps you could pose a separate question?  Both my regex and your modification work for me on that input...

Comment: In my mind this is the better answer as it actually checks the mixed use of ":" and "-".

Answer (score 12):

This regex matches pretty much every mac format including Cisco format such as `0102-0304-abcd`

```
^([[:xdigit:]]{2}[:.-]?){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2}$
```

Example strings which it matches:

```
01:02:03:04:ab:cd
01-02-03-04-ab-cd
01.02.03.04.ab.cd
0102-0304-abcd
01020304abcd
```

Mixed format will be matched also!

Comment: This will match separators after any of the first five octets, meaning that it will accept `aa.aa.bbbb.cccc`, for example.

Comment: **#notAllFormats** If you have access to an OSX system with WiFi, run `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I`, and look for the BSSID line, if any octet is under 0x10 leading zero is dropped (`%x` or `%2x` rather than `%02x` `printf` format used?)

Answer (score 9):

delimiter: "**:**","**-**","**.**"

double or single: 00 = 0, 0f = f

```
/^([0-9a-f]{1,2}[\.:-]){5}([0-9a-f]{1,2})$/i
```

or

```
/^([0-9a-F]{1,2}[\.:-]){5}([0-9a-F]{1,2})$/
```

```
exm: 00:27:0e:2a:b9:aa, 00-27-0E-2A-B9-AA, 0.27.e.2a.b9.aa ...
```

Comment: The second will incorrectly match strings which contain non-hex characters such as g.

Comment: The second one is not valid in most flavors, except for BRE/ERE, which supports character range collation. However, support for character range collation varies among implementation, so the result may vary.

Comment: Another thing is that the groups must have exactly 2 hexa-digits.

Comment: In theory all mac addresses returned by programs in the wild would follow some standard like 2 hex digits in each separate group.  However, some non-standardized [Unix variants](http://www.coffer.com/mac_info/locate-unix.html) shorten the output when there is a leading zero, leaving only 1 hex char in some cases.  Hence the need for the `{1,2}` regex

Comment: However, the character set from `[0-9a-F]` should probably be rewritten as: `[0-9a-fA-F]`

Answer (score 5):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258993/working-with-mac-and-ip-addresses-in-c/4259297#4259297) also.

Regexes as follows:

```
^[0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2}$

^[0-9A-F]{2}-[0-9A-F]{2}-[0-9A-F]{2}-[0-9A-F]{2}-[0-9A-F]{2}-[0-9A-F]{2}$
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to shorten it by doing groups? and how can I combine the regex to have either a : or a - without having 2 separate regular expressions?

Comment: The shortened form that netcoder provides will work also. Using one or the other may be based on whether you need to capture any of the MAC address or just validate it on the whole.

Comment: It needs to be validated on the whole, so if it either contains all hyphens or all colons.  If it contains a mix, it is not a valid MAC.

Comment: @Xaisoft: Like I said in my answer's comment, mixing colons and hyphens is valid according to the specification.

Comment: What source are you getting MAC addresses from that might have a mix of delimiters? If they are coming from an actual machine/NIC, you likely won't have that issue. If it is user-entered data, just perform a string replace to make all the delimiters consistent.

Answer (score 5):

Be warned that the Unicode property `\p{xdigit}` includes the FULLWIDTH versions. You might prefer `\p{ASCII_Hex_Digit}` instead.

The answer to the question asked might be best answered — provided you have a certain venerable CPAN module installed — by typing:

```
% perl -MRegexp::Common -lE 'say $RE{net}{MAC}'
```

I show the particular pattern it outputs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246077/simple-problem-with-regular-expression-only-digits-and-commas/4247184#4247184) as lucky pattern number 13; there are many others.

This program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings qw<FATAL all>;

my $mac_rx = qr{
    ^ (?&MAC_addr) $
    (?(DEFINE)
        (?<MAC_addr>
                (?&pair) (?<it>  (?&either) )
            (?: (?&pair) \k<it> ) {4}
                (?&pair)
        )
        (?<pair>    [0-9a-f] {2} )
        (?<either>  [:\-]        )
    )
}xi;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    printf("%-25s %s\n", $_ => /$mac_rx/ ? "ok" : "not ok");
}

__END__
3D:F2:C9:A6:B3:4F
3D:F2:AC9:A6:B3:4F
3D:F2:C9:A6:B3:4F:00
:F2:C9:A6:B3:4F
F2:C9:A6:B3:4F
3d:f2:c9:a6:b3:4f
3D-F2-C9-A6-B3-4F
3D-F2:C9-A6:B3-4F
```

generates this output:

```
3D:F2:C9:A6:B3:4F         ok
3D:F2:AC9:A6:B3:4F        not ok
3D:F2:C9:A6:B3:4F:00      not ok
:F2:C9:A6:B3:4F           not ok
F2:C9:A6:B3:4F            not ok
3d:f2:c9:a6:b3:4f         ok
3D-F2-C9-A6-B3-4F         ok
3D-F2:C9-A6:B3-4F         not ok
```

Which seems the sort of thing you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this : `(([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[-:]){5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\.){2}[0-9A-Fa-f]{4})`

Answer (score 4):

If you are using PHP, you can make use of [`filter_var()`](http://www.php.net/filter-var):

```php
// Returns $macAddress, if it's a valid MAC address
filter_var($macAddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_MAC);
```

As it seems, it supports MAC addresses in the following formats (x: a hexadecimal digit):

```
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
xxxx.xxxx.xxxx
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks a lot to [@Moshe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) for the [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4260512/5697714) above. After doing some more research I would like to add my extra findings, both in regards to IEEE 802 and enforcing consistent separator usage in regex.

> The standard (IEEE 802) format for printing MAC-48 addresses in
>   human-friendly form is six groups of two hexadecimal digits, separated
>   by **hyphens -**. It is however, widely adopted convention to also allow **colon :**,
>   and three groups of four hexadecimal digits separated by **periods .**.

Full credit to [@Moshe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) here for his initial statement, and to [@pilcrow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/132382/pilcrow) for [pointing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260467/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-a-mac-address/4260512#comment50799022_4260512) that IEEE 802 only covers hypens.

Here is a regex that enforces that same separator is used throughout the mac address:

```
^(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}(?=([-:]))(?:\1[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}){5}))$
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/hECRwF/2)

And here is an additional one that allows for use of no separator at all:

```
^(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}(?=([-:]|))(?:\1[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}){5}))$
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/hECRwF/1)

Answer (score 3):

```
/(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}[:-]){5}(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{2})/
```

Comment: Is this similar to pilcrow's answer, just without the :xdigit?

Answer (score 2):

The python version could be:

```
re.compile(r'\A(?:[\da-f]{2}[:-]){5}[\da-f]{2}\Z',re.I)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/^(([a-fA-F0-9]{2}-){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{2}|([a-fA-F0-9]{2}:){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{2}|([0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\.){2}[0-9A-Fa-f]{4})?$/
```

The regex above validate all the mac addresses types below :

```
01-23-45-67-89-ab
01:23:45:67:89:ab
0123.4567.89ab
```

Comment: I think this is the only one that's complete and correct.

Comment: What if you also wanted to match with no delimiters? ie: 0123456789ab

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the shortest possible, in PCRE (Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions, e.g. used in PHP):

```
/([\da-f]{2}[:-]){5}[\da-f]{2}/i
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the main RegEx is correct as it also classifies

```
'3D-F2-C9:A6-B3:4F'
```

as a valid MAC Address, even though it is not correct.
The correct one would be:

```
((([a-zA-z0-9]{2}[-:]){5}([a-zA-z0-9]{2}))|(([a-zA-z0-9]{2}:){5}([a-zA-z0-9]{2})))
```

So that every time you can choose ':' or '-' for the whole MAC address.

Comment: change `a-zA-z0-9` to `a-fA-F0-9` a mac is hex

Answer (score 1):

to match both 48-bit EUI-48 and 64-bit EUI-64 MAC addresses:

```
/\A\h{2}([:\-]?\h{2}){5}\z|\A\h{2}([:\-]?\h{2}){7}\z/
```

where \h is a character in [0-9a-fA-F]

or:

```
/\A[0-9a-fA-F]{2}([:\-]?[0-9a-fA-F]{2}){5}\z|\A[0-9a-fA-F]{2}([:\-]?[0-9a-fA-F]{2}){7}\z/
```

this allows '-' or ':' or no separator to be used

Comment: In PCRE `\h` is horizontal whitespace (e.g. tab or space, but not CR or LF)

Answer (score 1):

A mac address can be **48 bits or 64 bits.**

```
ad:12:13:fc:14:ee // 48 bit, with colons
ad-12-13-fc-14-ee // 48 bit, with dashes
ad1213fc14ee      // 48 bit, without any delimiter
AD:12:13:FC:14:EE // 48 bit, uppercase.

AD:12:13:FC:14:EE:FF:FF // 64 bit, uppercase
ad:12:13:fc:14:ee:13:ad // 64 bit, lowercase
ad-12-13-fc-14-ee-ff-ad // 64 bit, with dashes
ad1213fc14eeffae        // 64 bit, without any delimter
```

If you are looking for a regular expression that can validate both and all the above cases (which are valid) the following would work:

For 48 bit we can use this:

```
^[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}([:-]?)(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}\1){4}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}$
```

For 64 bit we can use this:

```
^[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}([:-]?)(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}\1){6}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}$
```

If you are looking for a single regex to validate both kinds of mac addresses, use an OR operator to concat them.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[\da-f]{2}([-:])([\da-f]{2}\1){4}[\da-f]{2}$/i
```

It uses backreferencing to ensure no mix between `:` and `-` is used.

The `i` flag makes it case insensitive.

Also, you might not need non-capturing groups, so you can make it a bit less complex.

matches

```
02:32:a3:fa:3b:03
02-32-a3-fa-3b-03
02-32-A3-FA-3B-03
```

won't match

```
02-32-A3-FA-3B
02:32:a3:fa:3b:03a
02-32:a3:fa:3b:03
02:32:a3:fa-3b:03
02-32-A3-FA-3B-03-
```

---

In javascript, you can also construct it from multiple regexes like this, might be more readable:

```js
const macRegex1 = /^(?:[\da-f]{2}[-]){5}(?:[\da-f]{2})$/;
const macRegex2 = /^(?:[\da-f]{2}[:]){5}(?:[\da-f]{2})$/;
const macRegex = new RegExp(`^${ macRegex1.source }|${ macRegex2.source }$`, 'i');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following procedure by passing mac address for validation,

```
private static final String MAC_PATTERN = "^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$";

private boolean validateMAC(final String mac){          
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(MAC_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mac);
    return matcher.matches();             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP Folks:

```
print_r(preg_match('/^(?:[0-9A-F]{2}[:]?){5}(?:[0-9A-F]{2}?)$/i', '00:25:90:8C:B8:59'));
```

Need Explanation: http://regex101.com/r/wB0eT7

Answer (score 0):

As a MAC address can be 6 or 20 bytes (infiniband, ...) the correct answer is:

```
^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:){5}(([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:){14})?([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$
```

you can replace : with [:-.]? if you want different separators or none.

Answer (score 0):

This could be used tested in sublime with my MAC address
This solution will only work with ideal MAC address That will look like this.. `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`

```
(([a-fA-F0-9]{2}[:]){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{2})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Cisco format**:

```
([0-9A-Fa-f]){4}\.([0-9A-Fa-f]){4}\.([0-9A-Fa-f]){4}
```

Matches:

```
1111.abcd.2222
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need spaces between numbers, like this variant

```
3D : F2 : C9 : A6 : B3 : 4F
```

The regex **changes** to

```
"^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}\\s[:-]\\s){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$"
```

Answer (score -1):

This one is a small one:

```
(([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]?){6})
```

Have in mind, that weird mix of several chars or separators could pass.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to pile on with an answer here because there is no single solution to scan both 48-bit and 64-bit MAC addresses in one regex, and many of the other solutions allow mixed delimiters or can't handle no delimiters.  I also took advantage of the 'ignore-case' flag to shorten the basic hexadecimal character group that appears three times here:

```
/[\da-f]{2}(?=([-:]?))((\1[\da-f]{2}){2})?(\1[\da-f]{2}){5}/gi
```

[\da-f] is the shortest way to specify hexadecimal digits, scan upfront for two of them.  Then do a lookahead to load up capture group 1 with the delimiter you want to use (or none).  Then create an *optional* pair of hexadecimal pairs to handle the 64-bit case. Then finish with 5 hexadecimal pairs.  Once again specify the /i flag to ignore case on the a-f.

If I were implementing this, I would also add a negative lookbehind near the beginning and a negative lookahead at the end to ensure I rejected excess hex-delimiter pairs, but that just complicates the answer and not all regex implementations handle lookbehinds or have all the same features, so I left that out.

Here's Regex101 on @Shwetabh 's example set.
[image]

Answer (score -5):

the best answer is for mac address validation regex

```
^([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]:){5}([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])$
```