# Find partial MAC address via RegEx

Tags: regex, mac-address

For my application, I require a RegEx which can find out if a string is *at least* partially a MAC address, but so far I have only found the following RegEx which only finds if something is a complete MAC address

```
^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$
```

**What would be a RegEx (possibly derived from the one stated above) which returns a full match for these 3 strings:**

1. `93:31:13:E1:D3:1A`
2. `3E-EB-47-8`
3. `84:0C:`

**while not returning a match for these 2 strings:**

1. `6B-90-8Y-31-D1-7K`
2. `37-4H-31`

**Note: I would not say this is a "practical" duplicate of [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889830/perl-regular-expression-for-partially-matching-an-ip-or-mac-address) question as**

1. That question was never answered successfully despite it being ~6 years old
2. That question is directed towards a specific engine
3. None of the answers provided to that question work in all/any of the cases above

Comment: Try [`^[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}(?:[:-][0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2})*[:-]?$`](https://regex101.com/r/1MVDWG/1). Note it will also match `3E:EB-47-8`.

Comment: Ha, had almost the same: [`^[0-9A-Fa-f]{0,2}([:-][0-9A-Fa-f]{1,}){0,5}[:-]?$`](https://regex101.com/r/DAASxo/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Almost perfect, however, this matches infinitely long MAC addresses

Comment: So, what are other requirements you have not revealed yet? Looks like you need to study [limiting quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit). What length restrictions do you have in mind? BTW, here is a version with only 1 delimiter support and only up to 6 parts in the MAC address: [`^[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}(?:(?::[0-9A-Fa-f]{0,2}){0,5}:?|(?:-[0-9A-Fa-f]{0,2}){0,5}-?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/1MVDWG/3)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Well, It is meant to match both partial MAC addresses, and complete MAC addresses, which from what I can find are at most "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" or 2 characters*6 fields, the RegEx you included works perfectly except for the fact that it allows 1 too many ":"

Comment: @NopeNope You may want to have a look at my final answer too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match partial MAC addresses with just 1 type of delimiter, you may use

```
^[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}(?:(?::[0-9A-Fa-f]{0,2}){0,5}|(?:-[0-9A-Fa-f]{0,2}){0,5})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zIbvTk/1).

To match MAC addresses with both `-` and `:` mixed up in the string, you may use

```
^[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}(?:[:-][0-9A-Fa-f]{0,2}){0,5}$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DL8Kns/1).

**Regex details**

MAC address here can consist of 6 `:` or `-` separated 2-hex char parts, and matches it as one types.

- `^` - start of the string
- `[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}` - 1 or 2 hex chars
- `(?:`

  - `(?::[0-9A-Fa-f]{0,2}){0,5}` - 0 to 5 repetitions of a `:` followed with 0 to 2 hex chars
  - `|` - or
  - `(?:-[0-9A-Fa-f]{0,2}){0,5}` - 0 to 5 repetitions of a `-` followed with 0 to 2 hex chars
- `)` - end of the non-capturing alternation group
- `$` - end of string.