# JQuery / JavaScript MAC Address Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a regular expression for a MAC Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260467/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-a-mac-address)

I would like to validate a string to ensure that it is a valid MAC Address.

Any ideas in Jquery or Javascript?

I have the following:

```
var mystring= '004F78935612'  - This type of MAC Address
var rege = /([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]){5}([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])/;
alert(rege.test(mystring));
```

But its not all that accurate.

Ie. My tissue box is a valid MAC Address?!?

Thanks!

Comment: almost, just how to implement it in JQuery or JavaScript

Comment: @Pinch: The expression in that answer will work in JavaScript as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Taking the regular expression from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260467/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-a-mac-address), you would implement it like so:

```
var mystring= 'Hello';

var regex = /^([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})$/;

alert(regex.test(mystring));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s2WDq/

This regular expression searches for the beginning of the string `^`, then TWO hexidecimal digits `[0-9A-F]{2}`, then a colon or dash `[:-]`, five times over `(...){5}`, then a final group of TWO hexidecimal digits `[0-9A-F]{2}`, and finally the end of the string `$`.

Edit: in response to your comment, Pinch, that format is not considered a valid MAC address. However, if you wanted to support it, simply add a `?` in the right place:

```
/^([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]?){5}([0-9A-F]{2})$/
// question mark  ^ allows the colon or dash to be optional
```

Comment: I appreciate your work but a MAC Address in my case looks like 004F78935612

Comment: Modified pattern for your input could be `/^([0-9A-F]{2}){6}$/`, but that's not valid [notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address).

Comment: @Pinch see my edit. keep in mind that, according to the official specs, that is NOT a valid MAC address.