# Validate MAC and IP addresses in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a program to read in data from an excel sheet which contains a bunch of info about computers which will be entered by the user.  This excel file will then be converted to a different format for other uses.  I can read all the values no problem but I just need help validating MAC and IP addresses entered by the user to make sure the information is correct.  Some regular expressions for this would be great as I am sure I would use them again at some stage.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm quite sure similar questions have already been asked here. Try to search for them.

Comment: Have you any experience of regex? What have you tried?

Comment: A simple Google gives me [this][1] for IP addresses, and [this][2] for MAC addresses.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260467/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-a-mac-address

Comment: Sorry I was looking for java with regex, thanks for the links.  I found Java has a pattern class that can deal with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 "^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
    "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
    "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
    "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$"
```

Answer (score 1):

([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})

This is for mac address

Comment: This regex will match "12-34-56:78-90:AB", which is not quite a valid MAC Address. `[0-9A-F]{2}([:-])(?:[0-9A-F]{2}\1){4}[0-9A-F]{2}` will ensure that all of the separator characters are the same, but it still misses the technically-valid "1234.5678.ABCD" format.