# Qt 4.8.4 MAC Address QRegExp

Tags: regex, qt, qt4, qregexp

I'm trying to get Qt to match a MAC Address ( 1a:2b:3c:4d:5e:6f ) using a QRegExp. I can't seem to get it to match - what am I doing wrong?

I am forcing it to try and match the string:

```
"48:C1:AC:55:86:F3"
```

Here are my attempts:

```
// Define a RegEx to match the mac address
//QRegExp regExMacAddress("[0-9a-F]{1,2}[\.:-]){5}([0-9a-F]{1,2}");

//QRegExp regExMacAddress("[0-9a-F]{0,2}:[0-9a-F]{0,2}:[0-9a-F]{0,2}:[0-9a-F]{0,2}:[0-9a-F]{0,2}:[0-9a-F]{0,2}");

//regExMacAddress.setPatternSyntax(QRegExp::RegExp);

// Ensure that the hexadecimal characters are upper case
hwAddress = hwAddress.toUpper();

qDebug() << "STRING TO MATCH: " << hwAddress << "MATCHED IT: " << regExMacAddress.indexIn(hwAddress) << " Exact Match: " << regExMacAddress.exactMatch(hwAddress);

// Check the mac address format
if ( regExMacAddress.indexIn(hwAddress) == -1 ) {
```

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260467/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-a-mac-address

Comment: Yes - those solutions didn't work with Qt for me.

Comment: You have not shown what kind of data you are feeding it.

Comment: I edited the post to show the string I am trying to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example opening bracket is missing and `\.` is incorrect (read [help](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qregexp.html) for explanations), in both `a-F` matches nothing, due to `'a' > 'F'`.

The correct answer you can find in the comment of `kenrogers`, but I'll duplicate it for you:

```
([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})
```

If you want to match `.` you should use:

```
([0-9A-F]{2}[:-\\.]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})
```

If you also want to match lower case characters, you should use:

```
([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-\\.]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})
```

Comment: Thank you this matched --> ([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-\\.]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})

Comment: ```r'^(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})([-:])(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}\1){4}(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$'``` Does not allow mixing separators