# mac-address-validation in javascripts (00:00:00:00:00:00)

Tags: javascript

Can anyone send javascript code to validate the network mac address (eg. `02:41:6d:22:12:f1`) It accepts value from `00:00:00:00:00:00` to  `ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`. On keypress event of textbox, I need to allow characters `0-9`, `a-f` and `:` (colon). What I have so far is

```
macPattern = /^([0-9a-fA-F]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}$/i;
```

With this I am able throw exception for `ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff` but I also need to throw an exception for `00:00:00:00:00:00`. My pattern is not throwing an exception.

Could you please give me a pattern through which I should able to throw an exception for both  `ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff` and `00:00:00:00:00:00`.

Comment: Rather than trying to make a more complex regex, why not just first check the input for the values `ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff` and `00:00:00:00:00:00`, and then if it is neither of those, run it through the regex?

Comment: I would just use the regex as is, and add a quick check for the two known exceptions (just using !=).

Comment: The pattern you tried matches ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff and 00:00:00:00:00:00? Or does it match on only one of them? What do you want the pattern to match? (I thought, the - in the [:-] has to be escaped, but I'm not sure)

Comment: i need pattern which will through an exception for both case...but the one i am using only case of ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff throughing an exception not for 00:00:00:00:00:00

Comment: @fred02138: could you please give me compltely pattern

Comment: @Manu You don't need to alter the regex, just put an `if` statement or two before the regex check that explicitly checks for the all `f` and all `0` MAC addresses, and do your error handling for those two cases within that `if` statement's code block.

Comment: A regular expression is not synonymous with "do all the logic needed to validate input." If you have a requirement like excluding `ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff` and `00:00:00:00:00:00`, it would be much better to exclude those cases using ordinary programming logic as @ajp15243 suggested twice, rather than "could you please give me compltely pattern." P.S. Is someone telling you that you have to do it all in a single regular expression? If so, who and why? Is this homework? This definitely doesn't seem to meet any real-world standard for ensuring input is an actual MAC address.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260467/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-a-mac-address

Comment: After some checking, I see that there are 281,474,976,710,656 possible valid MAC addresses. That is exactly 2^48, which means that both of the cases you are trying to exclude are theoretically possible.

Answer (score 3):

```
var MACAddress = document.getElementById("MACAddress");
var MACRegex=new RegExp("^([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]:){5}([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])$");
MACRegex.test(MACAddress);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var re = /^(?!(?:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff|00:00:00:00:00:00))(?:[\da-f]{2}:){5}[\da-f]{2}$/i;
//               ^------------blacklist------------^  ^----------pattern---------^
re.test('ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff'); // false
re.test('ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:fe'); // true
re.test('00:00:00:00:00:00'); // false
re.test('00:00:00:00:00:01'); // true
// and of course
re.test('00:00:00:00:01'); // false
re.test('00:00:00:00:00:0g') // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh if we are answering about validating mac, here is mine: but this still doesn't answer the question: how to prevent characters that don't make up a mac address.

```
function isValidMac(mac) {
  var a = mac.split(':');
  if (a.length !== 6) {
    return false;
  }
  for (var i=0; i<6; i++) {
    var s = "0x"+a[i];
    if (s>>0 === 0 || s.length != 4) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that while the other answers are all valid, they missed the keypress aspect of the OP's question.
While that might not be important in this instance, I believe that the UX can be improved.

I would suggest;

```
-validating length =12
-accepting {0-9,a-f,A-F},
-alert {g-z,G-Z)   (invalid character)
-ignore all others  (including Tab, cr, lf, crlf)
-confirm exit after the 12th character
-display 3 forms; raw, couplet, quad
```

I have not yet had a chance to code but will submit and amend on completion

Answer (score -1):

My answer is:

```
^([0-9a-fA-F]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9a-fA-F][1-9a-eA-E]$
```

Comment: Why must only the last digit not be `0` or `f`? What about any of the other digits? That regex ends up not matching on any MAC address that ends in `0` or `f` (`12:34:56:78:9a:bf`, for instance, would not be matched), rather than excluding the case of all `0`s or all `f`s.