# How to get a substring matching a regular expression from another string?

Tags: java, regex, string

Couldn't seem to find anything Java-specific here in SO.

I'm trying to get at a MAC address.

For example:

String input = "9hin00:1b:63:84:45:e6n0hu";

I need to get "00:1b:63:84:45:e6"

where MAC address could be any set of characters, but always with the "..:..:..:..:..:.." pattern

Comment: check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260467/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-a-mac-address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex for matching MAC address:

```
(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{2}:){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{2}
```

#### [RegEx Dmo](https://regex101.com/r/sJ6yH2/1)