# Regular expression (Python) - match MAC address

Tags: python, regex, mac-address, regular-language

I have this text (from ipconfig /all)

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR8151 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet    Controller (NDIS 6.20)   
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 50-E5-49-CE-FC-EF   
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes   
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes    
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5cba:e9f2:a99f:4499%11(Preferred)    
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1(Preferred)    
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0   
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : ™ 06 €…‚…‘ˆ 2016 20:35:49   
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : ‰…™‰™‰ 09 €…‚…‘ˆ 2016 21:05:49   
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.138   
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.138   
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 240182601   
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-7A-1F-FC-50-E5-49-CE-FC-EF   
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.138   
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled    

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection* 11:   

   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Juniper Networks Virtual Adapter    
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 02-05-85-7F-EB-80     
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No    
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes    
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8dfb:6d42:97e1:2dc7%19(Preferred)     
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.2.7(Preferred)      
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255     
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :       
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 436340101     
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-7A-1F-FC-50-E5-49-CE-FC-EF    
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.0.6     
                                       172.16.0.91     
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

I want to mach only the Physical Address (MAC)

From here it's will be 2:
**50-E5-49-CE-FC-EF** and **02-05-85-7F-EB-80**

This ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260467/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-a-mac-address)) `([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})` will not work because
This will mach also **00-01-00-01-19-7A-1F-FC-50-E5-49-CE-FC-EF**
So I've fixed it to this `([^-])([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})([^-])`
 (force not `-` in the start and in the end)
But now I get in the mach the whitespace in the begining and in the end I get `/n`.
Here is the link: https://regex101.com/r/kJ7mC0/1

I need an *elegant* **regex** to solve it.

Comment: `/Physical Address.*([0-9a-f]{2}-?){6}/i`?

Comment: Like [`re.findall(r'(?<!-)(?:[0-9a-f]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9a-f]{2}(?!-)', s, flags=re.I)`](https://regex101.com/r/kJ7mC0/2)? See http://ideone.com/Z1RCV5

Comment: "Physical Address" is not good, I need to support also other language in cmd

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Try it in the link I sent, it's not working... :(

Comment: I tried it everywhere, it is working well. http://ideone.com/Z1RCV5  and https://regex101.com/r/kJ7mC0/2

Comment: Why don't you just [query the MAC from Python](https://pymotw.com/2/uuid/)? `from uuid import getnode;print( hex( getnode() ) )`?

Comment: @cheziHoyzer is it always a `-` that is used as separator? You could replace the `[:-]` with `-` then. Otherwise you would need to take care of the colon in the restrictions.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew now it's working!! thanks!!

Comment: @SebastianProske you're right, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the non-`-` symbols on both sides because the negated character class `[^-]`  matches and consumes the characters. To avoid getting these characters in the match value, you can use lookarounds:

```
p = re.compile(r'(?<!-)(?:[0-9a-f]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9a-f]{2}(?!-)', re.IGNORECASE)
                 ^^^^^^                                  ^^^^
```

The `(?<!-)` negative lookbehind makes sure there is no `-` before the value you need to extract, and `(?!-)` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `-` after this value.

If the `:` delimiter is not expected, replace `[:-]` with `-`. Use it with `re.findall`.

Also, all the `(...)` should be turned to `(?:...)` non-capturing groups so as not to "spoil" the match results.

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/Z1RCV5)

An alternative can be a regex with 1 capturing group capturing what we need, and matching what we do not need:

```
p = re.compile(r'(?:^|[^-])((?:[0-9a-f]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9a-f]{2})(?:$|[^-])', re.IGNORECASE)
```

It does not look that elegant, but will work the same way as `(?:^|[^-])` non-capturing group is not included in the `re.findall` results, and matches either the start of string or a symbol other than `-`. `(?:$|[^-])` matches the end of string or a symbol other than `-`.

Also, to shorten the pattern, you may replace `a-fA-F` with just `a-f` in the character classes and use the `re.IGNORECASE` or `re.I` flag.