# Extract MAC address and UUID from string

Tags: regex, powershell

I extract string containing a lot of text and both MAC address and UUID.
For example:

```
![LOG[AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA, 0A0A0000-0000-0000-0000-A0A00A000000: found optional advertisement C0420054]LOG]!><time="09:07:57.573-120" date="04-19-2017" component="SMSPXE" context="" type="1" thread="2900" file="database.cpp:533"
```

I would like to strip the output to only display the MAC Address (e.g `AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA`) and UUID (e.g `0A0A0000-0000-0000-0000-A0A00A000000`)

I don´t know how to trim the output.

Here is my script:

```
$Path = "\\AAAAAAAA\logs$"
$Text = "AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA"
$PathArray = @()
$Results = "C:\temp\test.txt"


# This code snippet gets all the files in $Path that end in ".txt".
Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.log" |
Where-Object { $_.Attributes -ne "Directory"} |
ForEach-Object {
If (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $Text) {
$PathArray += $_.FullName
$PathArray += $_.FullName
}
}
Write-Host "Contents of ArrayPath:"
$PathArray | ForEach-Object {$_}

get-content $PathArray -ReadCount 1000 |
foreach { $_ -match $Text}
```

Comment: Check regex for MAC and UUID and use them as a patern:
[MAC address regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260467/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-a-mac-address) [UUID regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136505/searching-for-uuids-in-text-with-regex)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter all files, you can use the `-Filter` switch of the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet. Also you don't have to load the content using the `Get-content` cmdlet yourself, just pipe the files to the `Select-String` cmdlet.

To grab MAC, UUID I just googled both *regex* and combined them:

```
$Path = "\\AAAAAAAA\logs$"
$Pattern = '([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}),\s+(\{{0,1}([0-9a-fA-F]){8}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){12}\}{0,1})'
$Results = "C:\temp\test.txt"

Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.log" -File | 
    Select-String $Pattern | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Matches.Value
    } | 
    Out-File $Results
```

Comment: Hi!
Thank´s a lot for helping out.
I guess I wasn´t completely clear. I want to specify one specific MACAddress and the rows where that MACAddress exists I would lika to display both the MACaddress and the UUID on screen (not a file).

Comment: Just replace the `Out-File` line with `Where-Object { $_ -Like 'YOURMAC*'}`

Comment: One more quick question.
Is it possible to output only unique rows aswell?

Comment: Sure, just pipe it to ` | Select-Object -Unique`

Comment: Never mind I solved it!
Where-Object { $_ -Like "$Text*"} | Get-Unique