# Print out only last 4 digits of mac addresses from 2nd column using awk in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have made a shell script for getting the list of mac address using `awk` and `arp-scan` command. I want to strip the mac address to only last 4 digits i.e (i want to print only  the letters `yy`)

```
ac:1e:04:0e:yy:yy   
ax:8d:5c:27:yy:yy   
ax:ee:fb:55:yy:yy   
dx:37:42:c9:yy:yy   
cx:bf:9c:a4:yy:yy
```

Comment: Can be done in so many ways. Did you try anything?

Comment: I have tried many things. removed all the unnecessary lines and rows. but I am unable to shorten the mac address. I have it stored in $2

Comment: Try this method also `awk -F":" '{print $NF":"$(NF-1)}' fileName`

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried so far.

Comment: @YashBhagwatkar, show us your expected output in code tags so that we could try to help you(though I provided solution but since expected output is not given so that is based on some assumptions only).

Comment: try `grep -oP '.*:\K.*'`

Comment: @PS.that only yields `yy`. This is how I'd use `grep`: `grep -oP '[^:]*:[^:]*$'`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `cut -d: -f5-`

(Options meaning: delimiter : and fields 5 and up.)

EDIT: Or in awk, as you requested:
`awk -F: '{ print $5 ":" $6 }'`

Answer (score 0):

here are a few

```
line=cx:bf:9c:a4:yy:yy
echo ${line:(-5)}

line=cx:bf:9c:a4:yy:yy
echo $line | cut -d":" -f5-
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you want to strip the trailing spaces, but it isn't clear whether you want `yy:yy` or `yyyy`.

Anyhow, there are multiple ways to it but you already are running `AWK` and have the MAC in `$2`.

In the first case it would be:

```
awk '{match($2,/([^:]{2}:[^:]{2}) *$/,m); print m[0]}'
yy:yy
```

In the second (no colon `:`):

```
awk 'match($2,/([^:]{2}):([^:]{2}) *$/,m); print m[1]m[2]}'
yyyy
```

---

In case you don't have `match` available in your `AWK`, you'd need to resort to `gensub`.

```
awk '{print gensub(/.*([^:]{2}:[^:]{2}) *$/,"\\1","g",$2)}'
yy:yy
```

or:

```
awk '{print gensub(/.*([^:]{2}):([^:]{2}) *$/,"\\1\\2","g",$0)}'
yyyy
```

---

**Edit:**

I now realized the trailing spaces were added by anubhava in his edit; they were not present in the original question! You can then simply keep the last n characters:

```
awk '{print substr($2,13,5)}'
yy:yy
```

or:

```
awk '{print substr($2,13,2)substr($2,16,2)}'
yyyy
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that the [mac address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) always is 6 octets, you probably could just do something like this to get the last 2 octets:

```
awk '{print substr($0,13)}' input.txt
```

While testing on the fly by using `arp -an` I notice that the output was not always printing the mac addresses in some cases it was returning something like:

```
(169.254.113.54) at (incomplete) on en4 [ethernet]
```

Therefore probably is better to filter the input to guarantee a mac address, this can be done by applying this [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4260512/1135424):

```
^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$
```

Applying the regex in awk and only printing the 2 last octecs:

```
arp -an | awk '{if ($4 ~ /^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$/) print substr($4,13)}'
```

This will filter the column `$4` and verify that is a valid MAC address, then it uses `substr` to just return the last "letters"

You could also split by `:` and print the output in multiple ways, for example:

```
awk '{if ($4 ~ /^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$/) split($4,a,":");  print a[5] ":" a[6]}
```

Notice the [exp ~ /regexp/](https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html#SEC26)

```
This is true if the expression exp (taken as a string) is matched by regexp. 
The following example matches, or selects, all input records with the upper-case letter `J' somewhere in the first field:
$ awk '$1 ~ /J/' inventory-shipped
-| Jan  13  25  15 115
-| Jun  31  42  75 492
-| Jul  24  34  67 436
-| Jan  21  36  64 620
So does this:
awk '{ if ($1 ~ /J/) print }' inventory-shipped
```