# regular expression for a Mac address in precise validation

Tags: regex

I'm working with a backend web, in which I have to validate mac address before saving it to database. What is the regex of mac address?

I have tried every single regex in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260467/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-a-mac-address)
but it does not work well

The regrex I'm currently using is
/(\A(([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:]){5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})|\A(([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[-]){5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{4}.){2}[0-9A-Fa-f]{4})\z)/

It can validate mac address according to [IEEE 802 standards](http://sqa.fyicenter.com/1000208_MAC_Address_Validator.html) such as 1a:1b:1c:1d:1e:1f or 1a-1b-1c-1d-1e-1f or 1234.qwer.asdf.zxcv

1a:1b:1c:1d:1e-1f return false.

But when I add any character after a correct string such as 1a:1b:1c:1d:1e:1fabcdefghi, it still return true as well.
How to fix the regex to return false when facing with "1a:1b:1c:1d:1e:1fabcdefghi"?

Edit: add "(" and ")" as in  @Wiktor's comment. It works

Comment: You should add `(` after the first `\A` and `)` before the last `\z`, https://regex101.com/r/LS9VJp/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, It works. Now I can understand a bit more about regex.