# Regular expression for validating 64 bit (8 byte) MAC addresses?

Tags: java, regex

I have already gone through [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260467/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-a-mac-address) that have answered validating mac addresses but they are exclusive to 48-bit mac addresses.
I am looking for a regex that can validate 8 bytes or 64-bit mac addresses. A 64-bit mac address looks something like this:(basically has 4 more hexadecimal digits than 48 bit)

```
00:13:a2:00:41:8b:93:7a
0013a200418b937a
AD:12:13:FC:14:EE:FF:FF
ad-12-13-fc-14-ee-ff-ad
```

Based on answers for validating 48-bit mac addresses I have come up with this but am looking for something simpler.

```
^((([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:){7})|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}-){7})|([0-9A-Fa-f]{14}))([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$
```

Comment: Do mixed symbols count? Such as `AD:12-13:FC-14-EE:FF:FF`? Or mixed cases like `aD:12:13:Fc:14:Ee:FF:Ff`?

Comment: @HaoWu Mixed symbols do not count for any kind of mac address. I can work with mixed cases but usually, the mac address will be in one case upper or lower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could capture the separator with `([-:]?)` which allows digits to be separated by a colon, dash, or nothing. Then for successive matches use a `\1` [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to ensure the separators are consistent. This will cut down on the repetitiveness.

```
^[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}([:-]?)(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}\1){6}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}$
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}(?:[:-]?)){7}(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}))$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wFRjKR/1/)

This has factor out the 3 options with `:`, `-` and `null` as group separator between 2 hex digits.

It also removed unnecessary brackets and unnecessary capturing groups.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can turn off case-sensitivity and use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*[_G-Z])\w\w([:-]?)(?:\w\w\1){6}\w\w$
```

See the online Java [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iJkAQr/1)

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(?!.*[_G-Z])` - Negative lookahead to prevent an underscore or any character G-Z.
- `\w\w` - Match two word-characters (`\w` equals `[0-9A-Za-z_]`).
- `([:-]?)` - Capture an optional colon or hyphen.
- `(?:` - Open non capture group:

  - `\w\w\1` - Two word-characters and a backreference to our capture group.
  - `){6}` - Close non-capture group and match 6 times.
- `\w\w` - Match two word-characters.
- `$` - End string anchor.