# jQuery - Find MAC in string and optionally format it

Tags: jquery, regex, formatting

I have a field on my site that allows the user to enter data. Often within that they will include a MAC address.

I need a way to find the MAC address within the string and if it is a delimited format offer to reformat it for them and then update the string.

As I see it there are four things to do here:

1. With in string find MAC address delimited with `:` or `-`  eg: `00:12:34:56:78:90` or `00-12-34-56-78-90` and return this as a var.
2. If var exists show a confirm box asking them if they want it formatting. I can do this is the var is there.
3. If they confirm reformat MAC removing delimiter - I think I can do.
4. Update string with new MAC address - this I'm assuming is a simple find of old var and replace with new var.

For example:

The user enters 'This is a string containing 00:12:34:56:78:90 within it.'
I need to find `00:12:34:56:78:90` show confirm, change MAC to `001234567890` and update string so it reads:

'This is a string containing 001234567890 within it.'

The MAC can appear anywhere in the string, start middle or end and may have whitespace around it.  The delimiter will be : or -

Does anyone have any ideas how I can do this, specifically step 1 ?

Thanks

Comment: This would be the perfect opportunity to practice regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex used from : [What is a regular expression for a MAC Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260467/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-a-mac-address)
Slightly modified to match the MAC Address present at any position

```js
let macRegex = /([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})/g;
let text = 'My Wifi MAC Address is 2C:54:91:88:C9:E3 and my bluetooth MAC Address is 3D-F2-C9-A6-B3-4F';
let macPresent = macRegex.test(text);
let getMac = text.match(macRegex);

let colonOrHypenRegex = /[:-]/g;
let firstMacReplaced = getMac[0].replaceAll(colonOrHypenRegex, '');
console.log({macPresent, getMac, firstMacReplaced})
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that and update shortly.

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to get this working as I need.