# Regular expression for a MAC Address with default value exception

Tags: yang, libyang

From the regex pattern for specific type of MAC address is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4260512/1294836).

`^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$`

While defining the MAC address variable under this pattern, how do I can define an exception of default value as empty string in yang files.

Example:

Yang file, regex definition

```
  typedef mac-address-type {
    type string {
      pattern "[a-fA-F0-9]{2}(:[a-fA-F0-9]{2}){5}";
    }
  }
```

Variable definition:

```
type aye:mac-address-type;
```

How do this variable also accept an empty string in default value.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number This yang file i am parsing through c++ & python API in project·

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Agreed!! Tags are amended.

Answer (score 1):

Define a new type that includes the existing one into its definition and therefore expands its value space. YANG has a `union` built-in type that allows you to do just that. A value is considered to be valid if it matches at least one type in the union of types.

In YANG version 1.1:

```
  typedef mac-address-type {
    type string {
      pattern "[a-fA-F0-9]{2}(:[a-fA-F0-9]{2}){5}";
    }
  }

  leaf mac-or-empty {
    type union {
      type aye:mac-address-type;
      type empty;
    }
    default "";
  }
```

In YANG version 1:

```
  typedef mac-address-type {
    type string {
      pattern "[a-fA-F0-9]{2}(:[a-fA-F0-9]{2}){5}";
    }
  }

  leaf mac-or-empty {
    type union {
      type mac-address-type;
      type string {
        pattern ''; // length 0; // as an alternative 
      }
    }
    default "";
  }
```

This would mean that the valid value space for the `mac-or-empty` leaf would be MAC addresses or an empty string.

Note: a MAC address type has already been published by the IETF as part of [ietf-inet-types](https://yangcatalog.org/yang-search/module_details/ietf-inet-types@2013-07-15) YANG module (ietf-inet-types:mac-address), [RFC 6991](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6991), so there's no need to define your own.

The `union` built-in type is described in detail in RFC 7950, [Section 9.12.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-9.12)

Comment: error: the value "" does not match its base type - no member type matched for the default value. To avoid this  error, "typedef empty" also need to defined.

Comment: @suneetsaini, ah, you seem to be relying on YANG version 1. Indeed, the above is only valid in YANG version 1.1, because this was one of the changes between versions.

Comment: @suneetsaini, at least I'm assuming that's what happened in your case. In should be irrelevant, whether a type is defined via a typedef or inlined like in my examples.

Comment: Thanks for answer. One more question if there is any other option in which we can define "leaf" without union.

Comment: @suneetsaini, the only way I can think of would be to define its type exactly as per your requirement; `type string { pattern '([a-fA-F0-9]{2}(:[a-fA-F0-9]{2}){5})?'; }` for example. You cannot re-use an existing typedef that way, however.