# C# - Determine if an IP address range contains a particular address

Tags: c#, string, ip-address, range, contains

In C#, assume that you have an IP address range represented as a string value:

"192.168.1.1-192.168.2.30"

and you also have a single IP address represented as a string value like:

"192.168.1.150"

What would be the **most elegant** way to determine if the address range contains the single IP address?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check a input IP fall in a specific IP range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138706/how-to-check-a-input-ip-fall-in-a-specific-ip-range)

Answer (score 14):

Cast the IP to 32bit integer (IP is 4 bytes, so it could be also represented as an integer).
Than checking the range is simply checking if the given IP (int) is between two other IPs (2 other ints).

```
if( low_range <= checked_ip <= high_range ){ TRUE! }
```

Comment: Excellent idea.  And for the lazy, (*grin*) here is a SO answer that should help with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461742/how-to-convert-an-ipv4-address-into-a-integer-in-c

Answer (score 4):

I just wrote a small library [IpSet](https://github.com/donnytian/IpSet) to check if the specified IP address is contained by a pre-defined range.

```
var set = IpSet.ParseOrDefault("192.168.0.*,10.10.1.0/24,192.168.1.1-192.168.2.30");
var result = set.Contains("192.168.1.150"); // true
```

Support both IPv4 and IPv6.
Support CIDR notation.
The underlying work is convert IP addresses to integers and compare them.