# Asp.Net Core allow IP ranges in CORS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors

I am using the standard ASP.NET Core middleware and I would like to allow IP address ranges (in my case, I am looking for the private IP address ranges), to ease development.

Currently, my middleware looks like this:

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080", "https://test-env.com")
           .AllowAnyHeader()
           .AllowAnyMethod());
```

But now I would like to add a range of IPs, e.g. `172.16.0.0–172.31.255.255`, in CIDR notation `172.16.0.0/12`. How do I do it?

I tried the following and neither seems to work:

- `http://172.16.0.0/12:4200`
- `http://172.16.*.*:4200`
- `http://172.16.*:4200`

Comment: What was your final solution?  I would love to allow all for a given IP range.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ASP.NET Core 2.0 introduced the ability to take full control over how an origin is validated, using the [`SetIsOriginAllowed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors.infrastructure.corspolicybuilder.setisoriginallowed?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Cors_Infrastructure_CorsPolicyBuilder_SetIsOriginAllowed_System_Func_System_String_System_Boolean__) method. Here's an example of how it might be configured:

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
    builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(MyIsOriginAllowed) 
           .AllowAnyHeader()
           .AllowAnyMethod());

// ...

private static bool MyIsOriginAllowed(string origin)
{
    var isAllowed = false;

    // Your logic.

    return isAllowed;
}
```

The callback passed into `SetIsOriginAllowed` is of type `Func<string, bool>` and is expected to return `true` for allowed origins and `false` otherwise.

In terms of validating against a range itself, there's another answer that might be helpful: [How to see if an IP address belongs inside of a range of IPs using CIDR notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622967/how-to-see-if-an-ip-address-belongs-inside-of-a-range-of-ips-using-cidr-notation).