# How to allow CORS with IP address in ASP.NET Core Web API project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi, ip-address

I am using the ASP.NET Core Web API project I want to allow CORS policy with someone's IP address and I would like to allow IP address ranges. Using this CORS method this is allow CORS for everyone I want to allow only one IP address. Can anyone help me?

This is my method to allow CORS for everyone in my `Program.cs` file.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// Add CORS support
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

// Enable CORS
app.UseCors();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Hi, did you check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55398058/asp-net-core-allow-ip-ranges-in-cors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SetIsOriginAllowed` to implement it.

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(policyBuilder =>
    {
        policyBuilder.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin =>
        {
            // Convert domain to IP 
            // be careful, domains can have multiple IPs
            var host = new Uri(origin).Host;
            var ipAddresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host);

            // List of allowed IPs
            var allowedIPs = new List<IPAddress>
            {
                IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1"), // Replace with your allowed IPs
                IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2")  // Another IP
            };

            return ipAddresses.Any(ip => allowedIPs.Contains(ip));
        })
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
});
```

Comment: Why parse the same IP addresses again and again each time the callback is invoked, though? Could you not parse them outside that callback once and for all? Also, I thought the OP was interested (for better or worse) in allowing IP _ranges_...

Comment: Hi @jub0bs, In my understanding, UseCors is originally a middleware. For other methods of using domain names, it will be parsed every time, right?

Comment: @JasonPan What I'm suggesting is that computing `allowedIPs` only needs to happen once (at initialisation), not every time the middleware is invoked.