# Regex for ip address/range

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, ip

I have a textbox and the only input that it should take is either a single ip address or a range in the form of: `10.2.3.4-10`

I have this so far:

```
string txt = "10.13.11.12-100";

        string re1 = "((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))(?![\\d])";   // IPv4 IP Address 1
        string re2 = ".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
        string re3 = @"\b([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\b";//"([0-255])";   // Integer Number 1

        Regex r = new Regex(re1 + re2 + re3, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        Regex r2 = new Regex(re1, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        Match m = r.Match(txt);
        Match m3 = r2.Match(txt);
        if (m.Success || m3.Success)
        {...}
```

Only thing is with that, if I have `100.100.11.11-256` it will still return true since it matches `m3.Success` above as true.

How to fix that?

Comment: This might help you with the regex part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address.  It might need tweaked slightly for your particular language.

Comment: You should be able to use the answer from here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address

Comment: try this class http://stackoverflow.com/a/2138724/1080742

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For the IP Range Regex:

```
^10.2.3.(?:[4-9]|10)$
```

For the single IP address: [Regular expression to match DNS hostname or IP Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address)

Comment: I think the OP wanted that *format*, not that IP range specifically.

Comment: That was just a sample, it should take any IP address, and any range not just from 10.2.3.4 to 10.2.3.4.10. This is for one ip address format `\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b` but not sure how to add the range to it (doesn't matter if its a valid address or not)

Comment: This answer is does not correspond to the user's range.