# Go/GoLang check IP address in range

Tags: go, ip-address

In Go/GoLang, what is the fastest way to check if an IP address is in a specific range?

For example, given range `216.14.49.184` to `216.14.49.191`, how would I check if a given input IP address is in that range?

Comment: How are your ranges represented?

Comment: Start: "216.14.49.184", End: "216.14.49.191". I found a solution online for CIDR, but that's not the data that I'm working with.

Comment: Just wondering, if you broke those strings to components and compared them numerically, would that produce correct result?

Answer (score 46):

IP addresses are represented as bigendian `[]byte` slices in go (the `IP` type) so will compare correctly using `bytes.Compare`.

Eg ([play](http://play.golang.org/p/c0qpmFCK_2))

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

var (
    ip1 = net.ParseIP("216.14.49.184")
    ip2 = net.ParseIP("216.14.49.191")
)

func check(ip string) bool {
    trial := net.ParseIP(ip)
    if trial.To4() == nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v is not an IPv4 address\n", trial)
        return false
    }
    if bytes.Compare(trial, ip1) >= 0 && bytes.Compare(trial, ip2) <= 0 {
        fmt.Printf("%v is between %v and %v\n", trial, ip1, ip2)
        return true
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v is NOT between %v and %v\n", trial, ip1, ip2)
    return false
}

func main() {
    check("1.2.3.4")
    check("216.14.49.185")
    check("1::16")
}
```

Which produces

```
1.2.3.4 is NOT between 216.14.49.184 and 216.14.49.191
216.14.49.185 is between 216.14.49.184 and 216.14.49.191
1::16 is not an IPv4 address
```

Answer (score 38):

This is already in the stdlib in the "net" package as a function called net.Contains. You dont need to rewrite code that already exists!

See documentation [here](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IPNet.Contains).

To use it you just have to parse the desired subnets

```
network := "192.168.5.0/24"
clientips := []string{
    "192.168.5.1",
    "192.168.6.0",
}
_, subnet, _ := net.ParseCIDR(network)
for _, clientip := range clientips {
    ip := net.ParseIP(clientip)
    if subnet.Contains(ip) {
        fmt.Println("IP in subnet", clientip)
    }
}
```

In case the above code doesn't make sense here is a [golang play link](https://play.golang.org/p/u6JBAlIBLa)

Comment: This is true... unless you have IP data that doesn't format neatly into subnets.

Comment: works for IPV6 as well

Answer (score 8):

The generic version for ipv4/ipv6.

ip.go:

```
package ip

import (
    "bytes"
    "net"

    "github.com/golang/glog"
)

//test to determine if a given ip is between two others (inclusive)
func IpBetween(from net.IP, to net.IP, test net.IP) bool {
    if from == nil || to == nil || test == nil {
        glog.Warning("An ip input is nil") // or return an error!?
        return false
    }

    from16 := from.To16()
    to16 := to.To16()
    test16 := test.To16()
    if from16 == nil || to16 == nil || test16 == nil {
        glog.Warning("An ip did not convert to a 16 byte") // or return an error!?
        return false
    }

    if bytes.Compare(test16, from16) >= 0 && bytes.Compare(test16, to16) <= 0 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

and ip_test.go:

```
package ip

import (
    "net"
    "testing"
)

func TestIPBetween(t *testing.T) {
    HandleIpBetween(t, "0.0.0.0", "255.255.255.255", "128.128.128.128", true)
    HandleIpBetween(t, "0.0.0.0", "128.128.128.128", "255.255.255.255", false)
    HandleIpBetween(t, "74.50.153.0", "74.50.153.4", "74.50.153.0", true)
    HandleIpBetween(t, "74.50.153.0", "74.50.153.4", "74.50.153.4", true)
    HandleIpBetween(t, "74.50.153.0", "74.50.153.4", "74.50.153.5", false)
    HandleIpBetween(t, "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334", "74.50.153.4", "74.50.153.2", false)
    HandleIpBetween(t, "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334", "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:8334", "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334", true)
    HandleIpBetween(t, "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334", "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:8334", "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7350", true)
    HandleIpBetween(t, "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334", "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:8334", "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:8334", true)
    HandleIpBetween(t, "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334", "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:8334", "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:8335", false)
    HandleIpBetween(t, "::ffff:192.0.2.128", "::ffff:192.0.2.250", "::ffff:192.0.2.127", false)
    HandleIpBetween(t, "::ffff:192.0.2.128", "::ffff:192.0.2.250", "::ffff:192.0.2.128", true)
    HandleIpBetween(t, "::ffff:192.0.2.128", "::ffff:192.0.2.250", "::ffff:192.0.2.129", true)
    HandleIpBetween(t, "::ffff:192.0.2.128", "::ffff:192.0.2.250", "::ffff:192.0.2.250", true)
    HandleIpBetween(t, "::ffff:192.0.2.128", "::ffff:192.0.2.250", "::ffff:192.0.2.251", false)
    HandleIpBetween(t, "::ffff:192.0.2.128", "::ffff:192.0.2.250", "192.0.2.130", true)
    HandleIpBetween(t, "192.0.2.128", "192.0.2.250", "::ffff:192.0.2.130", true)
    HandleIpBetween(t, "idonotparse", "192.0.2.250", "::ffff:192.0.2.130", false)

}

func HandleIpBetween(t *testing.T, from string, to string, test string, assert bool) {
    res := IpBetween(net.ParseIP(from), net.ParseIP(to), net.ParseIP(test))
    if res != assert {
        t.Errorf("Assertion (have: %s should be: %s) failed on range %s-%s with test %s", res, assert, from, to, test)
    }
}
```

Comment: Working perfect

Answer (score 4):

#### Go 1.18

You can use the new package [`net/netip`](https://go.dev/doc/go1.18#netip). The package defines the type `netip.Addr`:

> Compared to the net.IP type, this package's Addr type takes less memory, is immutable, and is comparable (supports == and being a map key).

You can compare IPs with the method [`Compare`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/netip#Addr.Compare):

> Compare returns an integer comparing two IPs. The result will be:
>
> - 0 if ip == ip2
> - -1 if ip < ip2
> - +1 if ip > ip2.
>
> The definition of "less than" is the same as the [Less](https://pkg.go.dev/net/netip#Addr.Less) method.

Assuming that you're dealing with IPv4 addresses, a simple in-range comparison might look like the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/netip"
)

func main() {
    ip1, _ := netip.ParseAddr("216.14.49.184")
    ip2, _ := netip.ParseAddr("216.14.49.191")

    myIP, _ := netip.ParseAddr("192.168.8.1")
    fmt.Println(inRange(ip1, ip2, myIP)) // false

    myIP, _ = netip.ParseAddr("216.14.49.185")
    fmt.Println(inRange(ip1, ip2, myIP)) // true
}

func inRange(ipLow, ipHigh, ip netip.Addr) bool {
    return ipLow.Compare(ip) <= 0 && ipHigh.Compare(ip) > 0
}
```

**Note**: In real-world code don't actually ignore errors from parsing the IP strings.

Answer (score 3):

I ported over the code from a C# example found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2138724/1655418

And for some reason it ends up being 1ms faster than Nick's solution.

My question was for the "fastest" way, so I figured I'd post mine and see what the community thinks.

```
package iptesting

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
    "net"
    "time"
    "bytes"
)

func TestIPRangeTime(t *testing.T) {
    lowerBytes := net.ParseIP("216.14.49.184").To4()
    upperBytes := net.ParseIP("216.14.49.191").To4()
    inputBytes := net.ParseIP("216.14.49.184").To4()

    startTime := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < 27000; i++ {
        IsInRange(inputBytes, lowerBytes, upperBytes)
    }
    endTime := time.Now()

    fmt.Println("ELAPSED time port: ", endTime.Sub(startTime))

    lower := net.ParseIP("216.14.49.184")
    upper := net.ParseIP("216.14.49.191")
    trial := net.ParseIP("216.14.49.184")

    startTime = time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < 27000; i++ {
        IsInRange2(trial, lower, upper)
    }
    endTime = time.Now()

    fmt.Println("ELAPSED time bytescompare: ", endTime.Sub(startTime))
}

func IsInRange2(trial net.IP, lower net.IP, upper net.IP) bool {
    if bytes.Compare(trial, lower) >= 0 && bytes.Compare(trial, upper) <= 0 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func IsInRange(ip []byte, lower []byte, upper []byte) bool {
    //fmt.Printf("given ip len: %d\n", len(ip))
    lowerBoundary := true
    upperBoundary := true
    for i := 0; i < len(lower) && (lowerBoundary || upperBoundary); i++ {
        if lowerBoundary && ip[i] < lower[i] || upperBoundary && ip[i] > upper[i] {
            return false
        }

        if ip[i] == lower[i] {
            if lowerBoundary {
                lowerBoundary = true
            } else {
                lowerBoundary = false
            }
            //lowerBoundary &= true
        } else {
            lowerBoundary = false
            //lowerBoundary &= false
        }

        if ip[i] == upper[i] {
            //fmt.Printf("matched upper\n")
            if upperBoundary {
                upperBoundary = true
            } else {
                upperBoundary = false
            }
            //upperBoundary &= true
        } else {
            upperBoundary = false
            //upperBoundary &= false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

My results:

```
=== RUN TestIPRangeTime
ELAPSED time port:  1.0001ms
ELAPSED time bytescompare:  2.0001ms
--- PASS: TestIPRangeTime (0.00 seconds)

=== RUN TestIPRangeTime
ELAPSED time port:  1ms
ELAPSED time bytescompare:  2.0002ms
--- PASS: TestIPRangeTime (0.00 seconds)

=== RUN TestIPRangeTime
ELAPSED time port:  1.0001ms
ELAPSED time bytescompare:  2.0001ms
--- PASS: TestIPRangeTime (0.00 seconds)

=== RUN TestIPRangeTime
ELAPSED time port:  1.0001ms
ELAPSED time bytescompare:  2.0001ms
--- PASS: TestIPRangeTime (0.00 seconds)
```

Comment: Those integer `ms` timings look a bit suspicious to me - you'll get more accurate results using a `Benchmark` - see the benchmarks section in: http://golang.org/pkg/testing/

Answer (score 2):

How about some implementation like inet_pton? The result is easy to be stored.

```
func IP2Integer(ip *net.IP) (int64, error) {
    ip4 := ip.To4()
    if ip4 == nil {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("illegal: %v", ip)
    }

    bin := make([]string, len(ip4))
    for i, v := range ip4 {
        bin[i] = fmt.Sprintf("%08b", v)
    }
    return strconv.ParseInt(strings.Join(bin, ""), 2, 64)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[see in gist](https://gist.github.com/wuyanxin/f452118a9804e0eb1aaf586b8895a545)**

ipmatcher.go

```
type IPMatcher struct {
    IP net.IP
    SubNet *net.IPNet
}
type IPMatchers []*IPMatcher

func NewIPMatcher(ipStr string) (*IPMatcher, error) {
    ip, subNet, err := net.ParseCIDR(ipStr)
    if err != nil {
        ip = net.ParseIP(ipStr)
        if ip == nil {
            return nil, errors.New("invalid IP: "+ipStr)
        }
    }
    return &IPMatcher{ip, subNet}, nil
}

func (m IPMatcher) Match(ipStr string) bool {
    ip := net.ParseIP(ipStr)
    if ip == nil {
        return false
    }
    return m.IP.Equal(ip) || m.SubNet != nil && m.SubNet.Contains(ip)
}

func NewIPMatchers(ips []string) (list IPMatchers, err error) {
    for _, ipStr := range ips {
        var m *IPMatcher
        m, err = NewIPMatcher(ipStr)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        list = append(list, m)
    }
    return
}

func IPContains(ipMatchers []*IPMatcher, ip string) bool {
    for _, m := range ipMatchers {
        if m.Match(ip) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func (ms IPMatchers) Match(ip string) bool {
    return IPContains(ms, ip)
}
```

ipmatcher_test.go

```
import "testing"

func TestIPMatcher(t *testing.T)  {
    a, errA := NewIPMatcher("127.0.0.1")
    if errA != nil {
        t.Error(errA)
    }
    if a.IP.String() != "127.0.0.1" || a.SubNet != nil {
        t.Error("ip parse error")
    }

    b, errB := NewIPMatcher("192.168.1.1/24")
    if errB != nil {
        t.Error(errB)
    }
    if b.IP.String() != "192.168.1.1" || b.SubNet == nil {
        t.Errorf("ip match error: %s, %v", b.IP.String(), b.SubNet)
    }
    if !b.Match("192.168.1.1") || !b.Match("192.168.1.2") {
        t.Error("ip match error")
    }
}

func TestIPMatchers(t *testing.T)  {
    var WhiteListIPs = []string{"127.0.0.1", "192.168.1.0/24", "10.1.0.0/16"}
    M, err := NewIPMatchers(WhiteListIPs)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }
    if !M.Match("127.0.0.1") || !M.Match("192.168.1.1") || !M.Match("192.168.1.199") ||
        !M.Match("10.1.0.1") || !M.Match("10.1.3.1") {
        t.Error("ip match error")
    }
    if M.Match("127.0.0.2") || M.Match("192.168.2.1") || M.Match("10.2.0.1") {
        t.Error("ip match error 2")
    }
}
```

**[see in gist](https://gist.github.com/wuyanxin/f452118a9804e0eb1aaf586b8895a545)**

Answer (score 1):

The [IPAddress Go library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) can do this quickly in a polymorphic manner with both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.  [Repository  here](https://github.com/seancfoley/ipaddress-go). Disclaimer: I am the project manager.

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/seancfoley/ipaddress-go/ipaddr"
)

func main() {
    isInRange("216.14.49.184", "216.14.49.191", "216.14.49.190")
    isInRange("2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:0370:7334",
        "2001:db8:85a3::8a00:ff:ffff", "2001:db8:85a3::8a03:a:b")
}

func getAddress(str string) *ipaddr.IPAddress {
    return ipaddr.NewIPAddressString(str).GetAddress()
}

func isInRange(range1Str, range2Str, addrStr string) {
    range1, range2 := getAddress(range1Str), getAddress(range2Str)
    addr := getAddress(addrStr)
    rng := range1.SpanWithRange(range2)
    fmt.Printf("%v contains %v %t\n", rng, addr, rng.Contains(addr))
}
```

Output:

```
216.14.49.184 -> 216.14.49.191 contains 216.14.49.190 true
2001:db8:85a3::8a00:ff:ffff -> 2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:370:7334 contains 2001:db8:85a3::8a03:a:b true
```