# Go - check if IP address is in a network

Tags: networking, go, ip-address, subnet

Given:

- a network address A: (`172.17.0.0/16`)
- and an IP address from a host B: (`172.17.0.2/16`)

**how can we say if B is in A?**

All addresses are string variables in the following form: `[IP address in dot-decimal notation]/[subnet mask]`. Should I try to do it by manipulating strings (initial thoughts). Is there a different path?

Here is the same question for Python:

- [How can I check if an ip is in a network in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819355/how-can-i-check-if-an-ip-is-in-a-network-in-python)

and another approach with Go:

- [Go/GoLang check IP address in range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882961/go-golang-check-ip-address-in-range)

**UPDATE March 2022**
 for Go 1.18, check the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71489903/1561148) by [blackgreen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4108803/blackgreen)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [Go net package](https://golang.org/pkg/net/) includes the following functions:

- [ParseCIDR](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#ParseCIDR): takes a string representing an IP/mask and returns an
  IP and an IPNet
- [IPNet.Contains](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IPNet.Contains): checks whether an IP is in a
  network

This should cover your needs.

Answer (score 12):

**UPDATE March 2022**
 for Go 1.18, check the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71489903/1561148) by [blackgreen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4108803/blackgreen)

Based on Zoyd's feedback...

https://play.golang.org/p/wdv2sPetmt

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {

    A := "172.17.0.0/16"
    B := "172.17.0.2/16"
    
    ipA,ipnetA,_ := net.ParseCIDR(A)
    ipB,ipnetB,_ := net.ParseCIDR(B)
    
    fmt.Println("Network address A: ", A)
    fmt.Println("IP address      B: ", B)
    fmt.Println("ipA              : ", ipA)
    fmt.Println("ipnetA           : ", ipnetA)
    fmt.Println("ipB              : ", ipB)
    fmt.Println("ipnetB           : ", ipnetB)
    
    
    fmt.Printf("\nDoes A (%s) contain: B (%s)?\n", ipnetA, ipB)

    if ipnetA.Contains(ipB) {
        fmt.Println("yes")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("no")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 11):

#### Go 1.18

You can use the new package [`net/netip`](https://go.dev/doc/go1.18#netip). The package defines the type `netip.Addr` which is a significant improvement over the old one:

> Compared to the net.IP type, this package's Addr type takes less memory, is immutable, and is comparable (supports == and being a map key).

You can check if an IP is within a network with the method [`Prefix.Contains`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/netip#Prefix.Contains):

> Contains reports whether the network p includes ip.
>
> An IPv4 address will not match an IPv6 prefix. A v6-mapped IPv6
> address will not match an IPv4 prefix. A zero-value IP will not match
> any prefix. If ip has an IPv6 zone, Contains returns false, because
> Prefixes strip zones.

An example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/netip"
)

func main() {
    network, err := netip.ParsePrefix("172.17.0.0/16")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    ip, err := netip.ParseAddr("172.17.0.2")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    b := network.Contains(ip)
    fmt.Println(b) // true
}
```

If the IP you want to check also has the subnet mask, like `172.17.0.2/16` as in your example, you can use `ip, err := netip.ParsePrefix` again, and then obtain the address with `ip.Addr()` and pass that to `Contains`.

Code in the playground: https://go.dev/play/p/ikWRpPa1egI

---

For those who are interested in the implementation details, you can see [this blog post](https://tailscale.com/blog/netaddr-new-ip-type-for-go/) by Brad Fitzpatrick (former member of the Go team). The `net/netip` package is based on that work.

Comment: Your methods  netip.ParsePrefix("172.17.0.0/16") is faster than previous :  
  
BenchmarkFib40-8     2038528        722.7 ns/op      160 B/op        8 allocs/op

against  net.ParseCIDR

BenchmarkFib40-8     1107955       1092 ns/op      288 B/op       17 allocs/op

Answer (score 9):

Based on tgogos's answer:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    A := "172.17.0.0/16"
    B := "172.17.0.2"

    _, ipnetA, _ := net.ParseCIDR(A)
    ipB := net.ParseIP(B)

    fmt.Printf("\nDoes A (%s) contain: B (%s)?\n", ipnetA, ipB)

    if ipnetA.Contains(ipB) {
        fmt.Println("yes")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("no")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[The ipaddress-go Go library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) supports both IPv4 and IPv6 in a polymorphic manner and supports subnets, including methods that check for containment of an address or subnet in a containing subnet.  It also allows for more than just CIDR subnets.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of that library.

Example code:

```golang
contains("172.17.0.0/16", "172.17.0.2/16")
contains("10.10.20.0/30", "10.10.20.3")
contains("10.10.20.0/30", "10.10.20.5")
contains("10.10.20.0/30", "10.10.20.0/31")
contains("1::/64", "1::1")
contains("1::/64", "2::1")
contains("1::/64", "1::/32")
contains("1::/64", "1::/112")
contains("1::3-4:5-6", "1::4:5")
contains("1-2::/64", "2::")
contains("bla", "foo")

func contains(network, address string) {
    one, two := ipaddr.NewIPAddressString(network),
        ipaddr.NewIPAddressString(address)
    fmt.Printf("%v contains %v %v\n", one, two, one.Contains(two))
}
```

Output:

```
172.17.0.0/16 contains 172.17.0.2/16 true
10.10.20.0/30 contains 10.10.20.3 true
10.10.20.0/30 contains 10.10.20.5 false
10.10.20.0/30 contains 10.10.20.0/31 true
1::/64 contains 1::1 true
1::/64 contains 2::1 false
1::/64 contains 1::/32 false
1::/64 contains 1::/112 true
1::3-4:5-6 contains 1::4:5 true
1-2::/64 contains 2:: true
bla contains foo false
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer above so people can easily copy and paste the code into their projects.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    // True
    firstCheck, err := cidrRangeContains("10.0.0.0/24", "10.0.0.1")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(firstCheck)
    // False
    secondCheck, err := cidrRangeContains("10.0.0.0/24", "127.0.0.1")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(secondCheck)

}

// Check if a certain ip in a cidr range.
func cidrRangeContains(cidrRange string, checkIP string) (bool, error) {
    _, ipnet, err := net.ParseCIDR(cidrRange)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    secondIP := net.ParseIP(checkIP)
    return ipnet.Contains(secondIP), err
}
```